# Surface Area of a cube as a function of its volume

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Expressing the surface area of a cube as a function of its volume is like plugging in the surface area into volume?  Analyzing $\text{S.A.}=6s^2$, and $V=s^3$ I would assume that the Surface area is plugged into the volume. So then
$$s=\sqrt{\frac{\text{SA}}{6}}$$
and the volume would 
$$V=\left(\frac{\text{SA}}{6}\right)^{3/2}$$

Comment: you want to have surface area in terms of volume, not volume in terms of surface area

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Area as a function of volume.  If someone gave you volume, how would you calculate area.  (Volume is the input and area the output.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is volume as a function of surface area. You want the other way around, meaning you'll need to invert what you have:
$$
\textsf{SurfaceArea} = 6(\textsf{Volume})^{2/3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One sixth of surface area = $a^2  =(a^3)^{2/3}=V^{2/3}$